# How to set round border to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

How can I set a round border to the panel squarePane? Should I do it with paintComponent or is there a method for this?

```
public void gameboard() {
   
    ui.frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel squarePane = new JPanel();
    squarePane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    squarePane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 700));
    squarePane.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 5, true));
    squarePane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    ui.frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    ui.frame.add(squarePane);
    ui.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ui.frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

This is what I mean by rounded borders
[image]

Comment: What exactly is is that your border should look like? Can you provide a simple drawing? :)

Comment: @monamona I have added an image to the question so that you can see what I mean